# What is protecting Lua from buffer over-read?

Tags: lua

I've been looking through the Lua source code. I have figured out where the VM gets the next instruction. It's the [first line](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lvm.c.html#vmfetch) of the `vmfetch` macro:

```
#define vmfetch()       { \
  i = *(ci->u.l.savedpc++); \
  if (L->hookmask & (LUA_MASKLINE | LUA_MASKCOUNT)) \
    Protect(luaG_traceexec(L)); \
  ra = RA(i); /* WARNING: any stack reallocation invalidates 'ra' */ \
  lua_assert(base == ci->u.l.base); \
  lua_assert(base <= L->top && L->top < L->stack + L->stacksize); \
}
```

However, I haven't been able to find any code in `vmfetch` or in [luaV_execute](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lvm.c.html#luaV_execute) that checks to see if `ci->u.l.savedpc++` is actually a valid address. What is preventing Lua from accidentally executing data at some random address?

Comment: I don't think that there's anything there to protect Lua from such cases. The VM keeps track of chunk instructions, and the jump points. It also doesn't provide methods that allows outside sources to modify its instruction data. So with that in mind, it's expected to be pretty safe.

Comment: As Lua manual says, "Lua does not check the consistency of binary chunks. Maliciously crafted binary chunks can crash the interpreter."  So, to make safe environment, you should disable `debug` library and prohibit loading user bytecode. The bytecode created from Lua source is considered to be always correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protection is in the compilation phase.  The byte-code generation, would not build a chunk without some termination in it.

Allowing your users to add compiled lua, without any "trust" is a vulnerability.  Games such as WoW - which allow user lua, only accept source code, ensuring they have control over the compilation process.